# if empty succeeds even when the variables aren't empty

Tags: php, if-statement

```
 if($yesorno == "NO") {
$status="error";
}elseif(empty($userid) || empty($password) || empty($charid) || empty($vault)) {
    echo "$userid\n";
    echo "$password\n";
    echo "$charid\n";
    echo "$vault\n";
$status="error";
}
```

It supposed to check if `$userid`, `$password`, `$charid` or `$vault` is empty, if they are, it's supposed to set `$status` to error. However, when these variables contain something it stills sets it to error. As you can see I tried adding so that it echoes every variable, and the output is the four different values.

Why isn't it skipping the echo if they are all not empty? I can post more code if you say what specifically, I am not sure what's relevant, except what I already posted.

Comment: Paste more code like assigning values to `$userid, $password, $charid, $vault`

Comment: You should provide what exactly each variable contains. Right now I don't quite see any problems.

Comment: Replace `||` with `&&` and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   $yesorno = false;
    if(!$yesorno) {
        $status="error";
    }
    if(empty($userid) || empty($password) || empty($charid) || empty($vault)) {
        echo "$userid\n";
        echo "$password\n";
        echo "$charid\n";
        echo "$vault\n";
        $status="error";
    }
```